# How to remove "redirect notice" from Google Plus share message (using Google Plus share plugin)

Tags: google-plus

When a user clicks a link on my page they go to a click tracking service and then are redirected to the "real" page.  When I try to share the link using the Google Plus share plugin, the share message states "redirect notice."

Anyway for Google's Share plugin to actually go to the redirected destination instead of the notice?  The Facebook Share plugin has no problem with the redirect.

Example of link on my page:  https://plus.google.com/share?url=www.myclickservice.com?ref=www.realpage.com

The click tracking service logs the click and then returns a 302 and redirects to the "real" page.

Comment: Please provide an example page/redirect.

Comment: I provided an example.  The Facebook share plugin has no problem handling the 302 redirects from the click tracking service.

Comment: Not using a real example URL doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Snippet documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/) makes no guarantee about handling redirects. If you would like to see the current behaviour change, please [file a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list).